# Could anyone literally translate this JavaScript function in an easy-to-understand way?

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

https://codepen.io/zchee/pen/ogzvZZ

The above codepen link contains an example of scroll animation that changes the behavior and look of the navigation as you scroll down, which is done with pure vanilla JavaScript. The problem is I do not get how this script works. I have a basic knowledge in JavaScript and so far I am aware that...

1. There are 3 varaibles -- section (that selects "section" classes), an empty objects {}, and i that has a value of 0 inside a function.
2. After doing a research, I found out that **Array.prototype.forEach.call** is the same as **[ ].forEach(function())**. So from my understanding, e is a parameter. From here, I am lost as I don't know the meaning of 
   **section[e.id] = e.offsetTop;**
3. Okay so I understand window.onscroll = function() {} but not 100% sure the why we need to make a variable for scrollPosition that is equal to scrollTop or body.scrollTop?

And I am lost for the rest of the codes... I appreciate a line by line interpretation. Thank you.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
  var sections = {};
  var i = 0;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(section, function(e) {
    sections[e.id] = e.offsetTop;
  });

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i in sections) {
      if (sections[i] <= scrollPosition) {
        document.querySelector('.active').setAttribute('class', ' ');
        document.querySelector('a[href*=' + i + ']').setAttribute('class', 'active');
      }
    }
  };
})();
```

Comment: Creating a `scrollPosition` variable isn't *necessary*, but it allows it to be used later in a *short* `if` statement (it would look much worse if it was `if (sections[i] <= (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop)) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you have a look at the function, you can see that it is an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) which just means it a function that is executed as soon as it is encountered. When the function runs, it does the following:

```
var section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
```

This finds all the nodes that has a class of `section`. This returns a `NodeList`. This will represent `<div id="home" class="section"></div>` etc.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(section, function(e) {
sections[e.id] = e.offsetTop;
});
```

It's a way of iterating over a list that has properties like an Array. If it was an array, forEach would be called on it directly (As per @RobG below). This will store the `id` attribute of each `section` into the `sections` object which is used as a lookup with the offset top value i.e. how far from the top is each section when it is rendered.

```
window.onscroll = function() {}
```

Event handler that will fire every time you scroll.

```
var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
```

How far from the top have you scrolled so far.

```
if (sections[i] <= scrollPosition) {
    document.querySelector('.active').setAttribute('class', ' ');
    document.querySelector('a[href*=' + i + ']').setAttribute('class', 'active');
  }
```

This runs through all the sections and checks if you have scrolled at least as much down the document as what that section is from the top. If you have, then find the currently active section and remove its class, it isn't active anymore. Then go find the `a` tag, which represents the menu link associated with that section up top and go set its class as active.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I have a better understanding of it. I will gradually take your explanation and practice more using a similar method on my own.

Comment: "*find the currently active section*" it's actually "*find the first element with an  `active` class*", that's an actual flow in the code, would indeed have been better to find the currently active section, just like the code is not checking if the <section> actually has an `id` and is really one that should map to their anchor, nor is it using strict attribute checking for the anchors, so if they have sections   `domain`, `maintenance`, `main`, it will break.

Answer (score 1):

Since other people already gave you the explanation, I will just try to rewrite it to be somehow more readable?

```js
{
  let sectionNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("section"),
      sectionTopPositions = {}
      
  for (let node of sectionNodes) {
    sectionTopPositions[node.id] = node.offsetTop
  }
  
  function onWindowScroll() {
    let scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop
      || document.body.scrollTop
    
    for (let [nid, topPos] of sectionTopPositions) {
      if (topPos <= scrollPosition) {
        let activeNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("active"),
            linkNodes = document.querySelector(`a[href*=${nid}]`)
        
        activeNodes.className = ""
        linkNodes.className = "active"
      }
    }
  }
  
  window.addEventListener("scroll", onWindowScroll)
}
```